# Use int as num in function call

Tags: dart

I am learning Dart, and I defined a sum function to sum list of numbers.

```
sum(numberList) => numberList.reduce((num a, num b) => a + b);
```

When I call it on list of numbers:

```
main() {
  var nl = [4, 2, 4, 5, 9];
  print(sum(nl));
}
```

I got error:

```
type '(num, num) => num' is not a subtype of type '(int, int) => int' of 'combine'
```

This confused me, why a function defined for type num cannot be called on list of int? How to fix this problem? If the list 'nl' is coming from outside of my code, how can I cast `list of int` to `list of num`? (It seems List of int is not a list of num? puzzled.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `reduce` on a `List<int>`.
The type of that is `int reduce(int Function(int, int) combine)`.

That means that the `combine` function argument must be a function returning an `int`.
You try to pass a function which returns a `num`, and that is not allowed.

You didn't catch that statically because you haven't typed the argument to `sum`.
Try changing it to:

```dart
num sum(List<num> numberList) => numberList.reduce((num a, num b) => a + b);
```

What you can do is cast the list to `List<num>` before passing it to `sum`:

```dart
print(sum(nl.cast<num>()));
```

Comment: Thanks. What does `combine` in the type mean?  Is there any documentation refers to "combine"?

Comment: The function parameter to `reduce` is named [`combine`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-core/Iterable/reduce.html). It's just the name of the positional parameter, it has no effect other as documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I cannot give a real answer to your but here are some methods so solve your issue.
First of all obviously cast your list to an num list, either by specifying the generic type or using .cast :

```
  var nl = [4, 2, 4, 5, 9];
  print(sum(nl.cast<num>()));

  var nl = <num>[4, 2, 4, 5, 9];
  print(sum(nl2));
```

or you might want to use an extension which will work just fine for any list type which extends num:

```
extension SumList<T extends num> on List<T> {
  T sum() => reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}

  var nl4 = [4, 2, 4, 5, 9];
  print(nl4.sum());
```